# unchecking all check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

i am currently trying to produce a filter for a potential website.

in the filter there is 4 categorys:

- Continent
- Country
- Competition
- Date

within each of these category there will be a selection of checkbox options.
in the continent option it will always have:

- Europe
- Africa
- Asia
- North America
- South America
- Australia / Oceania

when one of these options is click a list of countries will appear within the country category. And when i click on one of the countries a list of football competitions that take place in that country will appear in the competition section.

example of problem:
i've selected:

- Europe
- England
- Premier League
- no date Selected

then i decide i don't want to view this and click on the Europe checkBox to remove all selected. However this does not happen, so how do i deselect Premier League and England when i have deselected Europe?

Html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="accordion">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
            <label for="check-1">Continent</label>
                <form action="">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Europe</td><td> <input name="Continent" value="Europe" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td> 
                        <td>Africa</td><td> <input name="Continent" value="Africa" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>North America</td><td><input name="Continent" value="North_America" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td> 
                        <td>Asia</td><td><input name="Continent" value="Asia" type="checkbox"  onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td>                      
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sorth America</td><td><input name="Continent" value="South_America" type="checkbox"  onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td> 
                        <td>Australia / Oceania</td><td><input name="Continent" value="Austrilia_Oceania" type="checkbox"  onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td>
                    </tr>     
                    </table>
                </form>
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" />
            <label for="check-2">Country</label>
            <form action="">
                <div id="Europe" hidden="hidden">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Spain</td><td><input name="Country" value="Spain" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td>
                                <td>Germany</td><td><input name="Country"  value="Germany"type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>England</td><td><input name="Country" value="England" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(value,name)"/></td>
                                <td>Italy</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>France</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                                <td>Portugal</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Russia</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                                <td>Ukraine</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Belgium</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                                <td>Netherlands</td><td><input name="Country" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
                <div id="North_America" hidden="hidden" >
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td>USA and Canada</td><td><input name="Country" value="USA_and_Canada" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td>Mexico</td><td><input name="Country" value="mexico" type="checkbox"/></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-3" />
            <label for="check-3">League / Competition</label>
            <form action="">
                <div id="England" hidden="hidden">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Priemer League</td><td><input name="Competition" value="Priemer_league" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>Capital One Cup</td><td><input name="Competition" value="Capital_One_Cup" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>FA Cup</td><td><input name="Competition" value="FA_Cup" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>Championship</td><td><input name="Competition" value="Championship" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>League 1</td><td><input name="Competition" value="League1" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>League 2</td><td><input name="Competition" value="League2" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="Spain" hidden="hidden" >
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>La Liga</td><td><input name="Competition" value="La_Liga" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>Copa del Rey</td><td><input name="Competition" value="Copa_Del_Rey" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="Germany" hidden="hidden">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>BundesLiga</td><td><input name="Competition" value="BundesLiga" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>Bundesliga 2</td><td><input name="Competition" value="BundesLiga2" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3 Liga</td><td><input name="Competition" value="3Liga" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td>DFB Pokal</td><td><input name="Competition" value="DFB_Pokal" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS for making checkbox Lists appear & dissappear:

```
function showMe(value,name) {

    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chboxs[i].checked){
         vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(value).style.display = vis;
}
```

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fonuxefegu/edit?html,js,output) for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should consider posting a version of your code to reproduce your problem. Maybe on jsfiddle or similar. Good luck! (ended up adding it myself: http://jsbin.com/fonuxefegu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Are you trying to do this in plain Javascript ?

Comment: yes i am only using javascript as its just a quick draft of a potential fix for a current website that i have to do for my university course, it will at some point contain jquery, but at the minute i am unfimiliar with it so i'm trying to stick with javascript

Answer (score 0):

1st, I guess you may want to be using radiobutton instead of checkbox. (Should it be possible to select multiple continents, multiple countries, and multiple competitions? Or just 1 of each? If only 1 each, then use radiobuttons)

Anyways, for accomplishing what you want, you could add an event listener to your checkboxes change event, and when fired, check if dependant checkboxes should be unchecked (by dependant I mean, for example, England depends on Europe being selected), and hide what has to be hidden.

By the way, where and how are you using your `showMe` function? I only see it's definition. Perhaps you can alter that same function to achieve what you want

Comment: the showMe function is executed when the checkbox is clicked on, also i want to be able to use check button for showing multiple fixtures on a specified date of the users choosing. but an event listening sounds good ill  give it a go and see how i get on

Comment: Give it a try and let us know if you need any help with your new code :). Also, if you are able to use JQuery use it, you will not regret it, it simplifies a lot your work